# Luke 2:46 Where did Jesus sleep when left in Jerusalem?

Tags: jesus, luke

The boy Jesus was in Jerusalem for three days before being found by his parents:

> After three days they found him in the temple courts, sitting among
>   the teachers, listening to them and asking them questions.  (Luke 2:46
>   NET)

Where would a child in those circumstances sleep and eat for three days? Were there some sort of provisions of housing or board in the temple?

Answer (score 1):

NET  Luke 2:47 And all who heard Jesus were astonished at his understanding and his answers. (Luk 2:47 NET)

Jesus was in high esteem, would not be difficult to obtain temporary housing relief.